# is there a design pattern for complex aspnet UI validation?

Tags: asp.net, validation

As an example, say I have a single domain object with 100 properties.  In my UI I need complex validation of the style:

- If A = 1, show controls B, C, D.  B is required, C is not, and D is not required must be less than 30 if it is populated.
- If A = 2, show controls B, D, E.  B is not required, D is required but has no limits, and E is not required.
- If A = 3, show controls B, E, F.  B is required and must be more than 10, E is required, F is not required.
- If B = 3 and F = 5, then show control G, but only when A = 3.

You can see my problem here.  The relationships between the properties are hideously complex, with validation changing dependant on earlier values and in combination with other values.

How have people modelled and handled this in the past?  Validation does not need to very often, but a config/xml-based solution would probably be best.

Comment: Are you sure this domain object is does not have too many responsibilities?

Comment: Yes it does, but unfortunately it cannot be changed.

Comment: Breaking out the responsibilities would help with the validation...

Comment: Please explain how it would help and I'll see what can happen.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the Chain of Responsibilities pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern and here is a sample in C# http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx#_self1

Answer (score 1):

You could project this gigantic domain object into smaller objects containing only the subsets of properties needed and name them according to the scenario they are describing. It's creating some sort of ViewModel if you will.

There has to be a specific use case for each case of A = "X" or B = "Y" etc. If you are splitting things up you can define validation rules per ViewModel. Those ViewModels could also contain the visible/hidden settings for your controls.